# Is there a way to stack widgets and ignore overlapping?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a GUI using PyQt5 and I made the background of my widgets change color when you hover your mouse over them.  However, when I hover over a widget, the widget beneath it overlaps  and the background is cut off at the bottom.

[image]

Its because of the way I made the background, I had to space the widgets very close together and increase the border size in order to achieve that background effect, but it messes with the hover like I said before.  Is there any way to ignore this overlapping, or perhaps a different method I could use to draw the background without having to overlap the widgets?

Here is a screenshot of what I want in case my explanation was bad (The bottom widget works fine because there is nothing beneath it to overlap)

[image]

I will also attach my code here so you can see what I did

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(MyBar(self))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setFixedSize(450,550)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #121A2B;')

        self.checkbox_style='''
        QCheckBox
        {
            background-color : rgb(25,34,52);
            border-radius : 5px;
            spacing : 10px;
            padding : 15px;
            min-height : 15px;
        }
        QCheckBox::unchecked
        {
            color : rgb(159,172,168);
        }
        QCheckBox::checked
        {
            color : rgb(217,223,227);
        }
        QCheckBox::indicator
        {
            border : 2px solid rgb(105, 139, 194);
            width : 12px;
            height : 12px;
            border-radius : 8px;
        }
        QCheckBox::indicator:checked
        {
            image : url(red.png);
            border : 2px solid rgb(221, 54, 77);
        }
        QCheckBox::hover
        {
            background-color: #263450
        }
        '''

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)

        self.checkbox_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.checkbox1 = QCheckBox('checkbox1')
        self.checkbox_layout.addWidget(self.checkbox1)
        self.checkbox1.setFont(font)
        self.checkbox1.setStyleSheet(self.checkbox_style)

        self.checkbox2 = QCheckBox('checkbox2')
        self.checkbox_layout.addWidget(self.checkbox2)
        self.checkbox2.setFont(font)
        self.checkbox2.setStyleSheet(self.checkbox_style)
        
        self.checkbox3 = QCheckBox('checkbox3')
        self.checkbox_layout.addWidget(self.checkbox3)
        self.checkbox3.setFont(font)
        self.checkbox3.setStyleSheet(self.checkbox_style)

        self.checkbox3 = QCheckBox('checkbox4')
        self.checkbox_layout.addWidget(self.checkbox3)
        self.checkbox3.setFont(font)
        self.checkbox3.setStyleSheet(self.checkbox_style)

        self.layout.addLayout(self.checkbox_layout)
        self.checkbox_layout.setContentsMargins(15,7,290,350)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

class MyBar(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.title = QLabel("")

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bebas Neue")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.title.setFont(font)

        self.btn_close = QPushButton()
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(40, 35)
        self.btn_close.setStyleSheet("QPushButton::hover"
        "{"
            "background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #fc0703, stop: 1 #a10303);"
            "border : none;"
        "}"
        "QPushButton"
        "{"
        "background-color : rgb(25, 34, 52)"
        "}")
        self.btn_close.setFlat(True)
        self.btn_close.setIcon(QIcon("C:/Users/User/Documents/GitHub/guirebuild/close.png"))
        self.btn_close.setIconSize(QSize(15, 15))

        self.title.setFixedHeight(53)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_close,alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: rgb(25, 34, 52);
            color: white;
        """)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(MyBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.parent.width(),
                                self.parent.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        self.parent.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: By default, widgets cannot overlap when put inside a layout. That said, please provide a [mre], as your current code does *not* reproduce the issue (there are spaces between items) and also requires a `MyBar` class we don't know anything about.

Comment: I edited the code above to include the full code so you should be able to reproduce it now.  My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the stacking of new widgets, and the simplest solution would be to set a *transparent* background for those widgets if you're sure that they won't have a different background when *not* hovered:

```
        self.checkbox_style='''
        QCheckBox
        {
            background-color : rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
            ...
```

Unfortunately, this will ***not*** really solve your problem, as there are serious logical issues in your implementation.

First of all, setting hardcoded content margins of a layout based on the overall layout is a serious problem for many reasons:

- it forces you to change those hardcoded margins based on the menu contents;
- it is based on ***your*** assumption about the current available fonts, which could potentially make the UI elements partially (or completely) hidden;
- it doesn't allow you to properly add more objects to the layout;

After ***seriously*** considering the above matters (which are *very* important and should *never* be underestimated), the problem is that, while Qt allows to lay out items "outside" their possible position through QSS paddings, you need to consider the widget z-level, which by default stacks a new widget above any other previously created *sibling* widget (widgets that have a common ancestor), and that's why you see partially hidden check boxes.

The base solution would be to install an event filter, check if it's a `HoverMove` event type and then call [`raise_()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) to ensure that it's put *above* any other sibling:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        for check in self.findChildren(QCheckBox):
            check.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.HoverMove:
            obj.raise_()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Again, this will only partially solve your problem, as you'll soon find out that your hardcoded sizes and positions will ***not*** work well (remember, what you see on your screen is ***never*** what others see on theirs).

A possible solution would be to create a separate QWidget subclass for the menu, add checkboxes in there, and always compute the maximum height considering the padding. Then, to ensure that the widget box is properly put where it should you should add a `addStretch()` or at least a "main widget" (which is what is normally used for a "main window").

```
class Menu(QWidget):
    padding = 15
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setMaximumHeight(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 15, 0, 15)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.setFont(font)

        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QCheckBox
        {
            background-color : rgb(25,34,52);
            border-radius : 5px;
            spacing : 10px;
            padding : 15px;
            min-height : 15px;
        }
        QCheckBox::unchecked
        {
            color : rgb(159,172,168);
        }
        QCheckBox::checked
        {
            color : rgb(217,223,227);
        }
        QCheckBox::indicator
        {
            border : 2px solid rgb(105, 139, 194);
            width : 12px;
            height : 12px;
            border-radius : 8px;
        }
        QCheckBox::indicator:checked
        {
            image : url(red.png);
            border : 2px solid rgb(221, 54, 77);
        }
        QCheckBox::hover
        {
            background-color: #263450
        }
        ''')
        self.checks = []

    def addOption(self, option):
        checkBox = QCheckBox(option)
        self.checks.append(checkBox)
        checkBox.installEventFilter(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox)
        count = len(self.checks)
        self.setMaximumHeight(count * checkBox.sizeHint().height() - 15)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.HoverMove:
            obj.raise_()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.menu = Menu()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.menu, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

        for i in range(4):
            self.menu.addOption('checkbox{}'.format(i + 1))

        self.layout.addStretch()
```

Note that in the code above I still used an event filter while still using explicit *opaque* background colors, if you are fine with the parent background, you can avoid installing and using the event filter and only set the default background to the transparent `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)`.